# EF Code First - adding SQL View for 1:1 relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I started working on a EF Code First approach and auto-generated the database. Now I want to add another entity that maps to a SQL view and not a table. I'm using a view because the data (employee info) is in a separate database. I add the view and created an entity but I keep getting the error that the context has changed and I need to manuall delete/update the database or call the SetInitializer method. I think the problem is with my model definition or in my assumption on the DB changes.

The basic entities are AppUser (application specific user) and vEmp (view to employee data). Not much to the AppUser entity:

```
public class AppUser
{
    public AppUser()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(75)]
    public string ntUserDomainId { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    public virtual vEmp vEmp { get; set; } // this was commented out at first to generate tables

}
```

The vEmp entity is defined as this:

```
public class vEmp
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("AppUser")]
    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public string empStatus { get; set; }
    public string orgid { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string ntUserDomainId { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

}
```

To make this work I commented out the navigation property in AppUser so EF would generate the tables. Then I uncommented out the navigation property and ran into the error. If I try to keep the navigation property in then EF assumes a table and creates "vEmp" as a table. The view actually matches on the user NT ID to form the query results - we use Windows Authentication so every user has their NT ID inside the AppUser table.

From what I can tell the [Key, ForeignKey("AppUser")] line should tell EF how to manage the relationship. My only guess is that EF wants a cross reference table created to map between the two.

I am also wondering if perhaps the easier approach is to go DB first and use EF to generate a model from the DB. I did one test project with a similar vEmp entitye and an AppUser entity using the autogenerated EDMX and that seemed to work after I manually made the association. We have lots of shared databases so using views is going to be common and I wonder if code first is too difficult to work with in such situations.

**UPDATE**

I think I have proof that EF wants to create a table. I toyed with migrations and this is what I see:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.vEmps",
        c => new
            {
                AppUserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                empName = c.String(),
                empStatus = c.String(),
                orgid = c.String(),
                email = c.String(),
                ntUserDomainId = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.AppUserId)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AppUsers", t => t.AppUserId)
        .Index(t => t.AppUserId);

}
```

If I understand this correctly it appears that EF doesn't see the SQL view named "vEmp" and instead wants to create a table. Does this mean that code first doesn't work with SQL views?

**Update 2**
After many failed attempts to get the code first syntax working I created an edmx model from the database as it existed to test the DB first process. I added all the tables created with my code first logic and the SQL view that I added. Then I just created an association with the modeling tool from the table AppUser to the view vEmp. The modeling tool appears to have created this code:

```
<Association Name="vEmpAppUser">
  <End Type="JobControlModel.vEmp" Role="vEmp" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Type="JobControlModel.AppUser" Role="AppUser" Multiplicity="1" />
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="AppUser">
      <PropertyRef Name="AppUserId" />
    </Principal>
    <Dependent Role="vEmp">
      <PropertyRef Name="AppUserId" />
    </Dependent>
  </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

Everything else (the entities) looks the same. I ran a quick test with a console application and it appears to work fine.

I am not sure why this appears to work with a DB first approach but not the code first. The entities are defined the same. The only issue is trying to recreate what DB first calls an "association" using code first.

Answer (score 0):

EF will get the last migration history first every time the application runs. If you check it using profiler you will get something like

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model], 
    [Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId], 
        [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 
        [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion], 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'TheProjectName.TheContextName'
go
```

In the migration history table there is some-kind of check-sum that stores the information about the context and it might try to compare with the context in the application.

If you generated the database from EF then you modified the database manually and also modified the same changes in the classes / entities, you need to also run the migration to update the migration history table.

You can check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn519921.aspx) for further explanation.

## update

You could run empty migration to save the current `DbContext` state.

For example you added this view in the database

```
create view Bars
as
   select Id, Name from Foos
```

And you already created a class and a configuration that match the view (type and any constraint).

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public DbSet<Bar> Bars {get;set;}

modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().ToTable("Bars");
```

What you need to do is

- Add migration

  `PM> Enable-MIgrations`

  `PM> Add-Migration AddBarsView`
- Open `AddBarsView`, empty the `Up` and `Down` method, then run the migration

  `PM> Update-Database`

Your view will be ready to be used.

Comment: I used EF to create the database, then added a SQL view, and then tried to update the entity model to use the SQL view. EF seems to not recognize the SQL view and instead wants to create a new table by the same name. Or, my changes to the entity model aren't correct.

Comment: @pretzelb, You sure the view columns and the class properties match each other?

Comment: The columns and properties appear to match. I thought maybe the problem was my view was vEmp and it wanted vEmps but I recreated the DB and that still didn't help. I think the problem is EF wants to create a FK and the only way to do that is with a table, so migrations wants to create a table named vEmps even though the view vEmps already exists.